# 18.04 Swap Size Large than RAM

Tags: ram, memory-usage

Something happened after a recent update.  I have 5GB RAM installed (one 4GB card, one 1GB) on a **Toshiba L750D**.  After a recent update, it started running super slow.  I noticed it is only seeing 708.4 MB of ram with 4.5 GB of Swap.

Either it's seeing my RAM as swap and vice versa, or it stopped seeing the majority of my RAM.

I ran `dmidecode` and it recognizes all 5GB.

Passed Memtest with no errors.

Comment: Does the issue persist when you restart and choose an older kernel in the GRUB screen?